# Why all the double stars in the left half of the The Force Awakens star field?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, special-effects

There is a strange non-random effect in the star field used in *The Force Awakens*.

I expect others will question this, but I'm absolutely certain it was there.   I noticed it during the initial scene and then again during the credits, where I was able to stare and at ponder it for ten minutes.   This is not my imagination or pareidolia.

In the star field, nearly all the stars on the left half of the screen are double, and they are all oriented one above the other, some thing like this:

> **:**  ​​​​​ *:*  ​​​ <sub>**:**</sub> **:**  ​​​​​​​ <sup>:​</sup>​​​  *:*
>
> ​​​​​​​ <sup>:​</sup>​​​  *:* **:**  ​​​​​ *:*  ​​​ <sub>**:**</sub>  **:**

I looked at it with and without my 3D glasses.   And they are not perfectly oriented up-and-down or the same for all pairs.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?   Is it intentional?   Accidental?  Some side-effect of production?   Some side-effect of the three-dimensionalization?

(Can anyone capture a picture of this if they get the opportunity?)

**EDIT:**   I looked again, this time in a non-3D showing.   I did **not** observe it.   So either it was my imagination, or it's related to 3D somehow.

Comment: sounds like artifacts from the 3d conversion

Comment: @phantom42:   It may, but it's **really** obvious, isolated to the left half, and I wouldn't expect 3d-related issues to be in the up-down orientation.   And they are far enough apart and inconsistent enough that I don't think it's a resampling issue of some kind.

Comment: You are mistaken, it is lens flare.

Comment: @Politank-Z:   Ha!

Comment: @Politank-Z that's also called a coma in optics language.

Comment: well, the real question is whether or not this can be seen on the 2d version. i didn't notice anything like it.

Comment: @phantom42:   We need someone to make observations after they already know what to look for.

Comment: @Politank-Z - this should be THE answer :(

Comment: I am afraid this will have to wait till DVD/BlueRay release where we can get clear pictures in HD.

Comment: @DVK, I'm going to try to get a picture if I go again

Comment: By chance were you sitting on the right hand side of the theater?

Comment: Four downvotes? _Why?!_

Comment: @MichaelT, no,  I was dead center

Comment: The down votes are likely because this is relatively trivial, because you haven't provided a screenshot and because even if the effect does exist, the most likely reasons are that's it's either a coincidence or merely an artefact of the 3D conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they were simply following conventional wisdom, [Commonality of Binary Stars](http://www.dailygalaxy.com/my_weblog/2014/09/-will-earths-twin-have-two-stars-exoplanet-systems-with-binary-stars-are-much-more-common-than-was-b.html)

Another possibility is the [*Apparent Ellipse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star#Visual_binaries)

> After a sufficient number of observations are recorded over a period of time, they are plotted in polar coordinates with the primary star at the origin, and the most probable ellipse is drawn through these points such that the Keplerian law of areas is satisfied. This ellipse is known as the apparent ellipse, and is the projection of the actual elliptical orbit of the secondary with respect to the primary on the plane of the sky.

Pretty pic angle of view example:

[image: Pretty pic]

Comment: I don't think so.   It is **really** pervasive, but only on one side of the field.

Comment: Also, if that's what they were going for, they wouldn't all be in the up-down orientation.

Comment: This "apparent ellipse" talk doesn't even make sense.   That is just a theoretical estimate of the most likely orbit based on multiple observations.   It doesn't affect the actual appearance of the star at one point in time.